# PHP PCRE pattern

Tags: php, regex, unicode, utf-8

I want to understand the following pattern, step by step.

```
/\p{L}/u
```

/u is a modifier (http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> u (PCRE8)
>       This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. > Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8. This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater > on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern is checked since PHP > 4.3.5.

And what about the rest?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the PHP documentation about [escape sequences](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) to find out about `\p{xx}`, then [Unicode character properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) to find out what `\p{L}` does.

To elaborate:

- the `u`  modifier makes it possible to use Unicode escape sequences
- `\p{xx}` is a Unicode sequence with a certain property
- `\p{L}` is a Unicode sequence that matches a letter

Therefore, `/\p{L}/u` matches Unicode letters.